# Multiply number in text box and put in label

Tags: c#, textbox, label

i have 3 a textboxs that each go to their corresponding label. they are TB A to lbl A and TB B to label B and TB C to lbl C and a total lbl. A is multiplied by 150, B by 120, and C by 90. then total of labels is shown in total lablel. i am using C#

I have three textboxes (A, B, C) and three corresponding labels. When the user enters a number in textbox A, I want that number multiplied by 150 to be put into label A; multiplied by 120 for B, and 90 for C. Also, I have a fourth label for the total of all the multiplied numbers.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: The seven people following the label tag will be stoked to help, I'm sure.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've tried to answer your question below, but your question is hard to understand and unclear. It's considered polite to post your code and tell us what you've tried so far. Can you edit your question to provide more information?

Comment: SO is not for your homework.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any of your code, this is the best I can do:

```
int a = Convert.ToInt32(textboxA.Text) * 150;
int b = Convert.ToInt32(textboxB.Text) * 120;
int c = Convert.ToInt32(textboxC.Text) * 90;

lblA.Text = a.ToString();
lblB.Text = b.ToString();
lblA.Text = c.ToString();
lblTotal.Text = (a + b + c).ToString();
```

Comment: This is assuming the contents of the textboxes can be parsed to `int`, and your controls are named this way, and...

Answer (score 0):

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub btnexit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnexit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
Private Sub btnclear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnclear.Click
    TBAsold.Text = ""
    TBBsold.Text = ""
    TBCsold.Text = ""
End Sub
Private Sub btncal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btncal.Click

End Sub
```

End Class